Offline/online event listeners stopped working
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Testing: <span id="status">Not Detected! </span>
  </body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("offline", function (e) {
      alert("offline");
    });
    window.addEventListener("online", function (e) {
      alert("online");
    });

    // window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    //   setInterval(() => {
    //     const statusDisplay = document.getElementById("status");
    //     statusDisplay.textContent = navigator.onLine ? "Online" : "OFFline";
    //   }, 100);
    // });
  </script>
</html>


It is working in some computers but in my computer it is just working on Firefox browser and not on other browsers - chrome, Opera, Brave, Edge.
I am using
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Chrome Version
Version 122.0.6261.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I also tested on the latest version but not working.
Not getting any error but when setting 'offine' from network tab it is working fine.
But turning aeroplane mode on not triggering the event.
I tried all other methods too available on the internet but did not get any solution.
I want the solution. I want to show alert or message on no internet connection.
